# Using terminal in tab to open a file in that same tab

Tags: neovim, terminal

In Neovim it's good to have a terminal window open amongst the other windows (which are displaying regular buffers).  Sometimes, in the terminal, I'll want to edit another file. Ordinarily you'd just `vim filename` but I'd like that file to be opened as another window in the same tab.  Perhaps, for example, there some way of replacing the `vim` in `vim filename` so that this can be achieved?

It would be easier to do this than to use `:e filename` because in the terminal I might have changed folder to somewhere rather tedious to type.

Comment: As far as I know the only way to do this with Vim is per http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_file_in_already_running_vim_from_elsewhere . I'm not sure if Neovim retains this functionality or if you meet the X Window requirement.

Comment: what do you mean by "another window in the same tab"?

Comment: @laktak http://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/

Comment: Use [nvr](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote#demos) see the "Using nvr from within :terminal" section.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a split, so it is effectively in the same "tab". You just have to type `:split` or `:vsplit`, depending on whether you want it split vertically or horizontally. you can then specify the file you want to open like this (say you want a vertical split) `:vsplit e foo.txt`

Comment: I stated in the question that I didn't want to use :e.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin some time ago for Vim to enable client server communications without `+clientserver`.

https://github.com/laktak/vim-please

<del>You can try if it works for NeoVim:</del> install the plugin and run `Please`. In another terminal run `./please FILE` (in the scripts folder). The FILE should be opened in the original Vim instance.

@justin suggested that [nvr](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote) does the same for neovim:

```
It basically does two things:

    adds back the --remote family of options (see man vim)
    helps controlling the current nvim from within :terminal
```

Comment: The plugin installs but running :Please produces errors https://pastebin.com/xLTpdyRm  (nvim v0.2.1-182-g6e4e70f on redhat linux 7)

Comment: Apparently neovim does not support the jobs api. You could test it in Vim to see if this is what you want.

Comment: @laktak +clientserver is not related to "jobs api". [nvr](https://github.com/mhinz/neovim-remote) mimics the +clientserver features perfectly.

Comment: @JustinM.Keyes I guess you misunderstood my comment - the please plugin needs the jobs api.